# 1 base de datos para cada usuario o 1 base de datos para todos los usuarios

Tags: php, sql

Estoy realizando un proyecto web y tengo dudas de como hacer las bases de datos. 
Cada usuario que ingresa a mi sitio genera 500 registros en una base de datos.
Estoy diseñando la web para que tenga miles de usuarios, ¿que tengo que hacer?, ¿1 base de datos para cada usuario o 1 base de datos para todos los usuarios?.

Cada base de datos tendrá 6 tablas y en total 500 registros aproximadamente.

Si tengo 1 sola base de datos y llega un momento de tener millones de registros, cada consulta demoraría mas que si hago una consulta a una base de datos con 500 registros?.

Tengo un menú que al `div` lo actualizo con `jquery`, `ajax` y hago consultas con `php` a la base de datos, por eso necesito que sea bien rápido la consulta a la base de datos. En este momento de desarrollo las consultas responden rápido teniendo 500 registros.

Muchas gracias!

---

Agrego: Cada usuario genera 500 registros en total de los procedimientos, cada procedimiento genera de 1 a 4 registro aproximadamente.

Comment: no veo por que una consulta si centralizas todo en una base de datos tardaría demasiado, un usuario solo debe consultar si información, sin importar si existen otros 300 usuarios mas registrados, es decir solo debe poder acceder y hacer consultas a su info y no a la de los demás

Comment: Ese podría ser un problema de sistemas no de programación, se me ocurre que quizá si usas muchas bases de datos la cantidad de ficheros abiertos y/o generados también lleve a sobrecargas del sistema. Deberías hacer una prueba con datos, simulando la cantidad de usuarios que dices tendrás en un futuro y sacar conclusiones a partir de datos reales.

Comment: Yo, personalmente, lo que haría sería tener todo en una misma base de datos pero tomando la precaución de tener una clase de bases de datos, intermedia, que me abstrajese de esa particularidad. Así, si en un futuro tengo que usar el plan B, no me haga falta reprogramar nada, solo configurar la aplicación y extraer los datos a las bases de datos correspondientes.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @element. Además, va adepender de la consulta. No sabemos qué registros generará cada usuario, tu preocupación es que las consultas sean muy lentas. Hablas que cada usuario genera 500 registros, ¿pero eso es lo máximo por usuario? ¿O es lo que genera cada vez que hace 1 procedimiento? Esos detalles hay que conocerlos. He trabajado con bases de datos relativamente pequeñas, de 10 o 12 gigabytes, que es consultada miles de veces por hora...

Comment: ...las velocidades de respuesta varían de acuerdo a varios factores. Dos de los más importantes son: el sistema en que está instalado el servidor de base de datos, y la correcta indexación y normalización de las tablas. Entonces, como conclusión, no es la cantidad de usuarios o la cantidad de información lo que va ralentizar una consulta, sino la forma en que implementes tu solución y el sistema sobre el que corra. Hay muchos otros factores a tomar en cuenta antes de realizar una implementación.

Answer (score -1):

Un momento tuve tu misma preocupación. Así que hice mi propio experimento. Hice 200 tablas que se relacionaran entre si y tuvieran información de usuarios. Cree mas de 100 usuarios. Rellene la base de datos de un monto de información.  Y en realidad no me afecto en nada al hacer una consulta. Te recomiendo hacerlo en una misma base de datos.

Lo que ralentiza verdaderamente el aplicativo son las cantidades de consultas que se tienen que ejecutar en simultaneo. Eso si es fatal. Y para eso tendrías que mejorar tu servicio de servidores de mejor capacidad.